# Failed to insert the data using python.mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm new to using MySQL connector for python and I have the below-given data to be inserted into a table called "region_based_billings". I tried all possible ways to insert this data and it seems I missing a syntax not sure exactly where and for which data type? .

```
   date  = '2016-06-29'
   region = 'Asia Pacific'
   account_type = 'PRODUCTION ACCOUNT'
   product_type  = 'AmazonEC2'
   total= 10.58383305
   count = 21

   cursor = self.testdb.cursor()
   cursor.execute('INSERT INTO iaas.region_based_billing (date, region, account type, product type, total amount, no of products) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',(date, region, account_type,product_type,total,count) )

    self.testdb.commit()
    self.testdb.close()
```

My table objects are :

```
 desc  iaas.region_based_billing;

    date                   date   NO           PRI      
    region                 varchar(50)  NO          
    account type           varchar(65)  NO          
    product type           varchar(65)  NO          
    total amount           float    NO          
    no of products         int(255) NO
```

I know it's pretty basic, not sure what exactly causing the problem. I tried keeping single quotes for date type '%s', but still it didn't work.

Also here is the error

**mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type, product type, total amount, no of products) VALUES ('2016-06-29', 'Asia Pa' at line 1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove space between column names. column name should be a single word or words seprated by _.
In your case column name have gap. So these column should be:-

```
account type = account_type
product type = product_type
```

and so on...

Comment: Ahh thanks pal , that worked its my white space that's causing the whole problem

Answer (score 0):

Removed the white spaces and it resolved the problem. Thanks.

```
Serial_no       int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
date            date    NO          
region          varchar(50) NO          
account_type    varchar(65) NO          
product_type    varchar(65) NO          
total_amount    float   YES         
no_of_products  int(255)    NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here no of products has a datatype of int. But, you are using it has a string. For integer, you need to use **%d**.

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO iaas.region_based_billing (date, region, account type, product type, total amount, no of products) VALUES **(%s, %s, %s, %s, %f, %d)'**,(date, region, count_type,product_type,total,count) )

[You can check this example.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm)

Comment: Actually you could %s for all the data types using MySQL connector .  %d is not needed

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html